# Move develop changes to a new feature branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-flow

For my project I use *git-flow*. I have `master` and `develop` branch synchronized with remote-repo
Usually for all changes I create a `feature` branch, edit the files, commit the changes on the `feature` branch and close the branch with a merge in `develop`.

But sometimes I forget to create a `feature` branch and I edit files directly in `develop`. How can I move the canges in a new `feature` branch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've already made the commit to `develop`, and your history looks like this:

```bash
A---B---C---D develop
```

Here, `C` is the last correct commit on `develop`, and `D` should have been committed to a feature branch. Do the following (while on `develop`):

```bash
git branch feature      # creates feature branch pointing at D
git reset --hard C      # or HEAD^, HEAD~1, etc - resets develop back to C
```

This will result in:

```bash
A---B---C develop
         \
          D feature
```

This will also work well if you've made more than one commit, as you can substitute whichever commit reference you need to reset `develop` back to in the second command.

It's worth noting that `reset --hard` will discard any uncommitted changes. I would always advise only manipulating commit history with a clean working tree, but to avoid this you could use a [different reset mode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-emgitresetemltmodegtltcommitgt) like `--merge`, which will allow the reset as long as your uncommitted changes aren't to any files changed in `C...D`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use git stash for putting the changes to a new branch, see [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing#Creating-a-Branch-from-a-Stash)

So in master, after you made the changes (but didn't add or commit them) you could do:

```
git stash //stashes the changes
git stash branch featurebranchname //creates a new branch and applies the stash to it
```

Comment: It's not clear from your answer that you need to run `git stash` before running the `git stash branch` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I double checked and edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already committed these changes locally and haven't pushed yet, you can use a soft reset:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git checkout feature
git commit
```

Just replace the 1 in `git reset --soft HEAD~1` with the number of commits you want to soft reset.

Answer (score -2):

You can cherry pick the changes to new branch.